# Bucketize CFAbsoluteTimes into round day NSDates

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdate, buckets

I have an `NSArray` of `CFAbsoluteTime`s.  They *should* be sorted from earliest to latest, but if not I can sort them.

What I need to do is find the min and max date (e.g. Jan 1 to Jan 5) and create a bucketization that shows the count for each day between, e.g.:

```
Jan 1 - 1
Jan 2 - 0
Jan 3 - 4
Jan 4 - 0
Jan 5 - 3
```

Something like that.  What is the simplest way to turn the absolute times into a rounded `NSDate` of some sort I can count?  Intermediate forms don't really matter to me.  I just need to write a function that returns a count when given a date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably be happier working completely in Cocoa for this problem, using NSDate instead of CFAbsoluteTime.

Applicable document is the [Date and Time Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000039i).

The general approach you'll need is to work within an `NSCalendar`, which encapsulates all of the information about days per month, months per year, leap years, DST changes, all for a particular time zone. Convert your `NSDate` instances to `NSDateComponent` and you'll be able to extract the day and month numbers, then bucketize from there.

Remember that the function you write (return a count when given a date) will implicitly or explicitly have to handle NSCalendar and NSTimeZone values. The answer will vary by year (is it a leap year? does the interval include a leap day) and locale/date (are we observing Daylight Saving Time in this location right now?).